# Pycharm error "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)"

Tags: python, windows-10, pycharm, python-3.5, nvidia

I have a script testing on Pycharm, script working fine around 3-4 mins, then it says "Python stopped working" and the script is stop running. On the Pycharm output segment, it says `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`.

Is this a bug or something wrong with my computer/Pycharm?

Comment: PyCharm is commercial software, have you filed a report with JetBrains?

Comment: `0xC0000409` is `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`. You can find the culprit using a native Windows debugger such as WinDbg, e.g. `!analyze -v` when the debugger breaks in for an exception.

Answer (score 1):

fixed the same problem by upgrading driver for nvidia to 398.36. i was having problems running code using pyqt5 and matplotlib through pycharm but the driver update solved it. was not expecting this to be the issue but it fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Let me talk for  a case with Android emulator- gemu-system_86_64.
Have experienced the same error that “Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)”

Have played with bios settings, path to java, memory and disk speed enhansments, rolling back old original card drivers, Nvidia supports - no result.
Then I returned all default settings to above ones and:
Right clicked on Desktop and selected 'Nvidia control panel' -> 3d settings -> Manage 3d settings. You can see there  two tab: global settings.
Put all of them as clamp, off or '1'. 
And in  'programm settings' tab navigated to emulator app and also disabled all what s possible. Now all work just fine.
If any in future you can change them for a specific application.
Perhaps this will help somebody.